# angular reactive form doesn't support ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form group that I need to show one of the required inputs whit ngIf. but even when this input does not exist, formcontrol check it and return form is not valid. my code is like this
**html**:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <label>mobile</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="mobile" />

  <div *ngIf="!hasInfo">
    <label>firstName</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
    <label>lastName</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**ts**:

```
constructor(){
 this.formBuilder();
}

ngOnInit() {
    if (accountResponse.length > 0) this.hasInfo= true;
}

formBuilder() {
    this.myForm= new FormGroup({
      mobile: new FormControl(null, Validator.required()),
      firstName: new FormControl(null, Validator.required()),
      lastName: new FormControl(null, Validator.required()),
    });
 }

onSubmit(){
  if(this.myForm.valid){
    console.log("valid")
  }else{
    console.log("not valid")
  }
}
```

if hasInfo is true that not to show firstName and lastName, my form should return valid but is always not valid

Comment: The form model is abstract, and required means required. You want it to be conditionally required, so you need a custom validator that implements this condition.

Comment: when you declare a form field in the component Angular is looking for it it the template. so it won't be enough to use `*ngIf` on the template only. I would choose a different approach here and try to programmatically add or remove a control

Comment: I checked my form by custom condition and it's work, thank's for your help @Ingo Bürk

Answer (score 6):

You can add conditional validators on form initialization.

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (accountResponse.length > 0) this.hasInfo= true;
  this.formBuilder();
}

formBuilder() {
  const required = this.hasInfo ? Validator.required : null;

  this.myForm= new FormGroup({
    mobile: new FormControl(null, Validator.required),
    firstName: new FormControl(null, required),
    lastName: new FormControl(null, required),
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngIf` just prevents rendering your `div` in the `html` file and it does not change your reactive form validation on your `.ts` file. for your purpose try this:

.ts:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    if (accountResponse.length > 0) { 
      this.hasInfo= true;
      updateValidations();
    }
}

updateValidations() {
 if( this.hasInfo ) {
  this.myForm.get("firstName").clearValidators();
  this.myForm.get("firstName").updateValueAndValidity();
  this.myForm.get("lastName").clearValidators();
  this.myForm.get("lastName").updateValueAndValidity();
 }
}
```

based on the `this.hasInfo` changes, call this `updateValidations` function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add/remove required validators from the FormControls when `hasInfo` is changed

Check this article - [Dynamically Add/Remove Validators in Angular Reactive Forms](https://medium.com/@gouravkajal/dynamically-add-remove-validators-in-angular-reactive-forms-2f99c12c285a)